# Using Wordpress on XAMPP POST Content-Length of 26896206 bytes exceeds the limit of 200 bytes

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I'm trying to figure out where my configuration is wrong here, I'm trying to upload a theme to wordpress on localhost using XAMPP and I keep running into weird storage issues, this was also prevalent when i was trying to download a database file.

Anyways, when going to upload the theme I get:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 26896206 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   200 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I've read multiple answers over questions like this and have set the following in my `php.ini`

`post_max_size=200MB`
`upload_max_filesize 100MB`
`max_file_uploads=20`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using post_max_size=200M instead of post_max_size=200MB and same upload_max_filesize 100M instead of upload_max_filesize 100MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your WordPress.sql file using a zip in phpmyadmin this will resolve your issue